# Does managed property required full crawl?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I am using SharePoint Search REST API. I am referring [SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Suppose we have created managed property or lets suppose managed property gets automatically created for site columns. Suppose each column which has managed property has some data.

I want data to be returned using SharePoint Search REST API. So while querying SharePoint Search REST API on managed properties, do we require full crawl or incremental crawl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add/edit managed property, you need full crawl usually.

Check below official guideline. 
[here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx)